# How I can recover the previous state of my table in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Can someone explain me, how I can recover the previous state of my table in jupyter notebook? For example, I have a table with a column "prices" and I accidentally had set all this numbers to 0. How I can make a stepback to recover previous values of numbers in "prices". Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think you can. Unless you saved it in a pickle file before the changes

Comment: I dont think that the didnt provide something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if it will work but you can try navigating to your ipython directory and checking the history.sqlite file there might be a previous state of the table stored there somewhere!

If you're on windows just enter ipython locate, navigate to that directory and you will find it inside of profile_default.